# 802.11g high latency spikes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

Average pings from 1-14ms with 98% signal quality (less than a few meters from AP)

Once I start using any bandwidth (start a download, or upload. Especially a healthy linux iso torrent) average latency spikes up to an **unbelievable 2000-4000ms**. Once I hit the pause/stop button on the download the latency goes back down.

Even if the download is on another computer that is also connected to the same AP, it affects all wireless clients

I have tested this with multiple wireless adapters and multiple APs

The APs I tested were: **cisco/linksys e1000v1, wrt54gv1.1, wrt54gv5**

- DD-WRT 21676 micro on wrt54gv5
- DD-WRT 12548 vint eko mini on wrt54gv1.1
- DD-WRT 21676 mini on e1000v1

I have an Alfa AWUS036H that I used as a client. And, I even tested the wrt54gv5 as a client connected to the e1000 and WRT54gv1.1. Ethernet running from WRT54gv5 to desktop

The latency is so bad during high bandwidth use (actually, not even high bandwidth use, ANY type of usage at all causes latency to spike during that time), that it causes web pages to sometimes time out or load very slow.

I tested ping with `ping -t 192.168.1.1` on Windows and `ping 192.168.1.1` on my Android device

I would also like to point out that I have it set to channel 1 2412 mhz and there are no other wifi APs using that channel around me. However, I do not have the equipment to test non-wifi interference. I really wish I had a proper spectrum analyzer

**EDIT**: I should also point out that, when connected to the router via Ethernet, the latency stays close to **<1ms** during any time of high bandwidth use or torrenting (high simultaneous connection use). So this debunks the theory that the CPU can't keep up with the low-priority ICMP pings

Comment: What's the environment? Are we talking apartment building? or plot in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: Just saw the edit. NM

Comment: updated the OP, there is no wifi interference on channel 1 (2412 mhz)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a cap for the upload on your torrent client? Without that torrenting very easily eats up all your available bandwidth. Check out for example this:

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/optimizing-torrent-speed.htm

You seem to be pinging the router to determine performance. That's not a way to do it, ping is only a connectivity tool, not a performance tool. Ping is handled by the router CPU, which is also handling the NAT in your network. Ping has a very low priority, your router will give precedence to all other tasks before it will answer to ping. You need to ping through the device to get a rough idea of the actual latency.

Comment: >The latency is so bad during high bandwidth use, that it causes web pages to sometimes time out or load very slow

Comment: some times it even kicks people off the wifi. and on rare high use occasions i'll have to power off and power back on the router. so far the e1000v1 doesn't have to be rebooted, but the wrt54gv1.1 needed it too often